# Own FormFile model

Tags: file, asp.net-core, iformfile

currently I'm solving issue with loading of files - I have used IFormFile, but I need now to add a variable (boolean) to each file - to know if user marked this file as main file or additional file.

I have tried to make my own class:

```
public class MyFormFile :FormFile
    {
        public MyFormFile(Stream baseStream, long baseStreamOffset, long length, string name, string fileName) : base(baseStream, baseStreamOffset, length, name, fileName)
        {
            MainFile = true;
        }

        public bool MainFile { get;set;}
    }
```

But when I use this, I got no files in model. (When I'm using `List<IFormFile>` instead of `List<MyFormFile>` in model, then it works.

currently the files sent from browser looks like this:

> File {mainFile: true, name: "Test_Result.pdf", lastModified:
> 1597833278041, lastModifiedDate: Wed Aug 19 2020 12:34:38 GMT+0200
> (Central European Summer Time), webkitRelativePath: "", …}

What am I missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use model like this:

```
 public class FileInputModel
    {
        public FileInputModel(){
            MainFile = true;
        }
        public IFormFile File { get; set; }
        public bool MainFile { get; set; }
    }
```

And you can use ajax to post data with the structure of `FileInputModel` to controller,here is a demo:

TestController:

```
public IActionResult TestFiles(List<FileInputModel> files) {
            return View();
        }
```

View:

```
<form method="post">
    <input id="Files" type="file" multiple/>
    <input type="button" value="submit" onclick="Submit()"/>
</form>
<script>
    function Submit() {
        var pdata = new FormData();
        var files = $("#Files").get(0).files;
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length;i++) {
            pdata.append('files[' + i + '].File', files[i]);
        }
        $.ajax({
            url: "TestFiles",
            type: "POST",
            data: pdata,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function (data) {
            }
        });

    }
</script>
```

result:
[image]